# contract_requiring_verification_published event not getting detected - Pact - Contract Testing

Tags: pact, pact-broker, pactflow

we are exploring around the things that are mentioned in the **https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-workshop-js** and we have hosted the pact broker docker in the local machine, were we are able to see the consumer and provider activities but we are interested to see **contract_requiring_verification_published** event getting detected and triggering webhook

So far we have published numerous versions from the consumer as well from the provider but this **contract_requiring_verification_published** event didnt got detected so far

Are we missing something ? is there a way to explore around how this event is working ?

Please help...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jr6f.png)

Only contract_published, contract_content_changed are getting detected, contract_requiring_verification_published is not getting detected.

But based on the information what we see here : https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-workshop-js, contract_requiring_verification_published should also be detected if I am not wrong.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2wYX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of https://docs.pact.io/pact_broker/webhooks#the-contract-requiring-verification-published-event

It's possible that you're not using the branches and environments feature, which is one of the key determinants of that calculation.